# BDD to implement for a loop and validate

Tags: algorithm, loops, cucumber, carousel, bdd

I have a BDD scenario where it involves swiping left and checking the text on the page, which needs to be repeated "n" times due to it being a carousel.

My BDD looks like

```
Given I am on the carousel page
When I swipe left three times
Then I should see the text "Page [Page Number]" on each page
```

I'm unsure how I should add the step definitions here. If I add the swipeLeft() logic under the WHEN clause it makes it redundant to add the same logic in THEN clause and validate the text in it.

What should be the best way to optimise this scenario?
Is it getting rid of the WHEN clause entirely and just combine with THEN? What all best practices we can follow here, please. I believe user actions hould be included in the WHEN clause

```
const carouselPage = require('./pages/carouselPage');

Given('I am on the carousel page', async () => {
  await browser.url('https://example.com/carousel');
});

Then('I perform five swipes left and verify page text', async () => {
  const page = new carouselPage();

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    await page.swipeLeft();
    const text = await page.getText();
    expect(text).toEqual(`Page ${i}`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about the value of the carousel, and how to give an example of that value. What is it they're swiping for? I hope it's cats, because I like cats. So here is what I would have as my scenario:

```
Given the first three cats are Arcturus, Bob and Casper
When I go to the Cat Carousel page
Then I should see Arcturus
When I swipe right twice
Then I should see Casper
When I swipe left once
Then I should see Bob
```

I know there's a whole load of violating "only one assertion per test" going on there, but sometimes it takes more than one action to fully demonstrate the value of a behaviour, and I prefer "only one aspect of behaviour per test".

I would prefer to see this than something convoluted that doesn't actually demonstrate why you would want this behaviour to work.

I also find it helps to use particular examples rather than vague abstractions about what the code should do, as it's easier to imagine specifics. So try to pick some examples and set those up in your context.